# Correct usage of __str__ method for a dictionary (kwargs)

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, keyword-argument

I have a task to print correctly `kwargs` arguments of a class.

Here is my code:

```
 class Contact:
        def __init__(self, name, surname, number, selected=None, **kwargs):
            self.name=name
            self.surname=surname
            self.number=number
            self.selected=selected
            self.additional=kwargs
        def __str__(self):
            if self.selected==None:
                selected='No'
            else:
                selected='Yes'
            return 'Name: ' + self.name+'\n' + \
                   'Surname: ' + self.surname+ '\n' + \
                   'Phone: ' + self.number + '\n' + \
                   'In selected: ' + selected + '\n' + \
                   'Additional information: ' + '\n' + \
                   str(self.additional.keys()) + '\n' + \
                   str(self.additional.values())
         
    if __name__=='__main__':
        jhon = Contact('Jhon', 'Smith', '+71234567809', telegram='@jhony', email='jhony@smith.com')
        print (jhon)
```

I need to have in the end:

```
Additional information:
     telegram : @jhony
     email : jhony@smith.com
```

But all I've got is :

[image]

I've really tried to iterate over it, create lists, and I've got nothing, because the `___str___` method could only use `str` objects. How can I go through the kwargs arguments and take it in format of `key : value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `dict` referenced by `self.additional`.

```
def __str__(self):
    return ('Name: ' + self.name + '\n'
            + 'Surname: ' + self.surname+ '\n' + 
            + 'Phone: ' + self.number + '\n' +
            + 'In selected: ' + selected + '\n' +
            + 'Additional information: ' + '\n' + 
            + '\n'.join([f'     {k}: {v}' for k, v in self.additional.items()]))
```

Comment: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" @chepner